# How to pick values for specific times in a date (large list of date, time, value)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with these columns: date, times, and value of a stock.  Basically, per-minute value of stocks.  I would like to calculate the difference in the value of a stock at 10 AM and 4 PM.  This is the code I have so far:

```
fileName = "C:\\...\\US_200901_210907.csv"

with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
        split = line.split(";")
        time = split[3]
        date = split[2]
        for timev in f.readlines()[1:]:
            if timev == '100000':
                Spot = float(split[2])
            elif timev == '160000':
                Close = float(split[2])
        Diff = Spot - Close
        print(Diff)
```

I am not sure if I am doing this right.  But the code needs to cycle/loop through each date first, find the value of the stock at '100000' and '160000' and then calculate the difference between the two.  Then move to the next day. And at the end of all days, print the differences for each day.

The "Diff = Spot - Close" line also gives me an error, says "NameError: name 'Spot' is not defined"

Any help is appreciated.

Dataset looks like this (extract):
[image]

====================

After working more on this on my own, I was able to get this to work:

```
import csv
filename = "C:\\...\\US_200901_210907.csv"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader, None)  # skip header
    rows = list(reader)

listOfDates = []
index = 0
for row in rows:
    if rows[index][2] not in listOfDates:
        listOfDates.append(rows[index][2])
    index = index + 1
print(listOfDates)

startPrice = 0
endPrice = 0
index = 0

startPriceSet = False
endPriceSet = False

for date in listOfDates:
    for row in rows:
        if rows[index][2] == date:
            # print(rows[index][2])
            # print(date)
            if rows[index][3] == '100000':
                startPrice = float(rows[index][7])
                startPriceSet = True
            elif rows[index][3] == '160000':
                endPrice = float(rows[index][7])
                endPriceSet = True
            index = index + 1
            if startPriceSet and endPriceSet:
                print(date, startPrice, endPrice, startPrice - endPrice)
                startPriceSet = False
                endPriceSet = False
```

Comment: How does your csv looks like? Can you pls paste first few rows of it..?

Comment: The reason for `NameError: name 'Spot' is not defined` is you have `Spot` assigned in an `if` block hence it's scope remains in that `if` block only, define it as `Spot=0` and `Close=0` after your line of for loop

Comment: Added how the data set looks like in the question @bhagyesh dudhediya

Answer (score 1):

Why not leverage a **pandas DataFrame** for this calculation -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\...\\US_200901_210907.csv")

# give appropriate column names before or after loading the data
# assuming we have the columns 'time', 'date' & 'stockvalue' in df
# might have to use pandas.to_datetime

print(df[(df['time']=='time1') && (df['date']=='date1')]['stockvalue']-df[(df['time']=='time2') && (df['date']=='date1')]['stockvalue'])
```

Also, **why** do you have an **embedded for** loop?

Comment: Will this go through all dates in my dataset or just specific dates?  I see you define dates in there as date1.  My end goal is to have a difference between the 10 AM and 4 PM stock price for every date in the dataset. Regarding for loops, I am trying to learn and was not sure how to make it go through all dates.

Comment: take out all the unique dates via **list(np.unique(df['date'].sort_values()))**, then loop over this list via **for unique_date in your_list: print(df[(df['time']=='time1') && (df[date]==unique_date)]['stockvalue'] - df[(df['time']=='time2') && (df['date']==unique_date)]['stockvalue'])**

Comment: **time1 and time2** being **10 AM and 4 PM**, which gets used in the **filter** applied, ensuring it does not consider other time values for that same day.

Comment: here is what I got: 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\...\\US_200901_210907.csv')
your_list = list(df.unique(df['<DATE>'].sort_values()))
time1 = '100000'
time2 = '160000'
for unique_date in your_list:
    print(df[(df['<TIME>']=='time1') & (df['<DATE>']==unique_date)]['<CLOSE>'] - df[(df['<TIME>']=='time2') & (df['<DATE>']==unique_date)]['<CLOSE>'])

It gives me this error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: This does not seem to work

Comment: you have a typo, it is **np.unique()** not **df.unique()** , and ofcourse include **import numpy as np**, and is the time column datatype a **string?** if yes, then fine, but after initializing the variables time1 and time2, make sure you remove the **single inverted commas** when calling them in the filter condition.

Comment: Yes, I guessed on numpy.  I am getting this row repeated with this code: Series([], Name: CLOSE, dtype: float64)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/US_200901_210907.csv', sep=';')

your_list = list(np.unique(df['DATE'].sort_values()))
time1 = '100000'
time2 = '160000'

for unique_date in your_list:
    print(df[(df['TIME']=='time1') & (df['DATE']==unique_date)]['CLOSE'] - df[(df['TIME']=='time2') & (df['DATE']==unique_date)]['CLOSE'])

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach with the sheet you have provided:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx", header=None, dtype='str')

out = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
for rowindex, row in df.iterrows():
    date = row[2]
    name = row[0]
    if row[3] == "100000":
        out[name]['DATE'] = row[2]
        out[name]['START'] = float(row[4])
    if row[3] == "160000":
        out[name]['END'] = float(row[4])


for stock, data in out.items():
    print (stock+': DATE: '+data['DATE']+' START: '+data['START']+' END:'+data['END']+'  diff = '+str(int(data['END']-data['START'])))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks.  When I try to run the code, I get lots of rows some of which repeat each other (I did put an intent to the print(out) and next lines.  How would I print just the date, stock price at 10:00, stock price at 16:00 and the difference?

defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002A62F02E280>, {'SANDP-500': defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'START': 4521.61, 'END': 4520.07})})
SANDP-500 diff = -1.5399999999999636
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002A62F02E280>, {'SANDP-500': defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'START': 4521.61, 'END': 4520.07})})
SANDP-500 diff = -1.5399999999999636

Comment: That was because of an extra print `print(out)`. Have updated the code now to print date as well

Comment: Here is what I am getting, seems like it repeats some lines multiple times and is not showing prices at 10 and 16 and the date: 
(extract of last rows of output)
...
SANDP-500 diff = 14.44000000000051

SANDP-500 diff = 14.44000000000051

SANDP-500 diff = -1.5399999999999636

SANDP-500 diff = -1.5399999999999636

SANDP-500 diff = -1.5399999999999636

SANDP-500 diff = -1.5399999999999636

Comment: This doesn't look like the output of the edited code, the edited code also prints the date, etc

Comment: My bad, didn't note the changes in the code above.  When I tried to run it, got an error message saying "could not concatenate a str of a float."  So I changed to simply say this: for stock, data in out.items():
    print (data['DATE'], data['START'], data['END'], data['START']-data['END']).  When I ran it, it gave me a single line as the output: 09/07/21 4521.61 4520.07 1.5399999999999636. If I try to intend the print to move under the For statement, it then gave me multiple lines for each date (same lines for each day).  I appreciate your help with this but it does not seem to work.